# Add extra_hosts to docker file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker image which is based off node:12. This image, along with others, are brought up via a docker-composer.yml file. The issue I am having is that I am unable to add extra_hosts to the container. In my yml file - I've got the following

```
my-app:
  image: <image_name>
  container_name: <container_name>
  extra_hosts:
    - "somehost:162.242.195.82"
```

This appears to work with other containers but not ones based of node:12. Is this functionality not available to images based off node:12? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you get any specific error when trying to compose, or does it just not create the host for you?

Comment: Just doesn't create the host for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potential workaround:

Create a Dockerfile which uses `node:12` as your parent image and then write your host into the `/etc/hosts` manually. Then update your compose setup to build from that Dockerfile.

As mentioned below, this is purely a hacky workaround. It may be worth trying the other `node:12` distribution such as `node:12-alpine`.

Comment: It is a **very bad** idea to alter the /etc/hosts of an image manually and to build a new image with an altered /etc/hosts containing specific infos.

Comment: @MichéeLengronne - for my own learnings, whats the reason?

Comment: Docker relies heavily on `/etc/hosts` for its own network management. If you alter it manually, you can create conflicts between your values and what Docker sets. It can lead to connexion problems or data leakage.

Answer (score 1):

Check the base image of the `node:12`, you have other choices (Stretch, Alpine, Buster) https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

It is a **very bad** idea to alter the `/etc/hosts` of an image manually and to build a new image with an altered `/etc/hosts` containing specific infos.